# How to fix div width using scss (with react)

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I want to fix div width (image) and get scroll-bar. But the more add 'div', the smaller width of div in wrapper div area. It doesn't appear scroll-bar.

This is image-wrapper below.

```html
<div className="image-list-wrapper">{imageList}</div>
```

{imageList} are added by clicking button with 'div'

```html
    let imageList;
    if(images){
      imageList = images
        .map((image, i) => {
          return(
          <div key={i} className="image-list-item">
            <img className="image-resize" src={`http://localhost:5000`+image}/>
          </div>
          )
      })
    }
```

and CSS (SCSS)

```css
.image-list-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  width: 95%;
  height: 12rem;
  border: 1px solid #bcbaba;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-list-item {
  float: left;
  width: 9rem;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
}

.image-resize {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

I got result below (screenshot)(please ignore other buttons.)

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6V1O.png)

[screen shot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nloOj.png)

The more images, the smaller images.

I want scroll-bar and fixed width of div items in wrapper div.

Comment: why use float:left for image-list-item?

Comment: add `flex-wrap:wrap` to your wrapper

Comment: @FullStackEngineer Because I want to align all 'div's on a one line

Comment: @Pete It doesn't work too. :<

Comment: @user10953698, I mean you could do that using flexbox and looks like you are using it anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will generate something like this:

```
<div class="image-list-wrapper">
  <div key="0" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
  <div key="1" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
  <div key="2" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
  <div key="3" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
  <div key="4" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
  <div key="5" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
  <div key="6" class="image-list-item">
    <img class="image-resize" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x160">
  </div>
</div>
```

and you should remove float left because you either use floated elements or you use flexbox.

```
.image-list-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  width: 95%;
  height: 12rem;
  border: 1px solid #bcbaba;
  overflow-x: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-list-item {
  width: 9rem;
  height: 9rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
}

.image-resize {
  width: 100px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

which results into this: [Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/63gdvozm/5/)

Comment: By your answer, I got scroll-bar, but scroll-bar "Y". I want to get scroll-bar "X" and align on a horizontal line.

Comment: @user10953698 There are 2 ways to accomplish what you want: using flexbox or using floated elements. For floated elements you have to add another container inside image-list-wrapper and set it's width to the sum of the widths of all child elements so I removed my initial answer because that needs extra javascript and created a demo using flexbox which is pretty much your initial code without the float because flexbox doesn't need floated elements. It seems to work in my jsfiddle unless I'm missing something. Is the html I used above not what reactjs generates?

Comment: @user10953698 one other thing I suspect is  overflow-x: auto; on .image-list-wrapper is being overwritten by some other css. Try overflow-x: auto !important;